# Is 'take a sauna' the correct expression?

Tags: word-usage

I'm not a native English speaker and I was just wondering if *take a sauna* is a correct way to say that I'm going to sauna, the same way you can say *take a shower*. I have tried to search this up online, and the expression appears in some forum posts and [guides](http://www.wikihow.com/Take-a-Sauna) but I can't find anything official.

Comment: This is a tough one for native speakers. Saunas are not common in America, except in Finnish communities. That makes them special, and the rules more arbitrary. I'm sure Finnish has a verb based on _sauna_, but English doesn't. The most likely one is probly _have a sauna_; _take a sauna_ makes it sound like a personal cleansing event, like _shower_ or _shit_ (which can also be verbs). That may be appropriate, for some people and some saunas; but _have_ assumes less.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I didn't know that about have vs take. This must be the reason why I can't seem to find anything online, maybe there just isn't an official way. And yes in Finnish there is a verb, saunoa.

Comment: As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=going+to+have+a+bath%2Cgoing+to+take+a+bath%2Cgoing+to+have+a+shower%2Cgoing+to+take+a+shower&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgoing%20to%20have%20a%20bath%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgoing%20to%20take%20a%20bath%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgoing%20to%20have%20a%20shower%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgoing%20to%20take%20a%20shower%3B%2Cc0) shows, ***take*** has displaced ***have*** for baths and showers. So although ***sauna*** is too rare to show up on that chart, I expect it'll follow the same general trend.

Comment: I'm a Brit, and have often *had* saunas in Germany, and have also *had* them in the UK & elsewhere. Personally, I would normally say "*have* a bath / shower / sauna".

Comment: I would think one might *go **use** the sauna* or *go **sit** in the sauna*. Similar to how people talk about *hottubs*.

Comment: This is getting interesting, according to Ngram (thanks for @FumbleFingers for mentioning this tool), British English uses more *have a sauna* while American English prefers *take a sauna*. But unfortunately this still isn't anything official.

Comment: @Rathony that could also be a good way to express it. And as a side note, you could argue that saunas are private (in Finland at least), as many households have their own saunas, but this is a little off-topic.

Comment: Sauna:  (a period of time spent in) a room or small building, often with wood attached to the walls, that is heated to a high temperature, usually with steam:
***have/go for/take a sauna*** - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sauna - He talked about the benefits of taking a sauna regularly. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sauna

Comment: @Josh61 That should be an answer.

Comment: To **have** a (bath/shower/sauna) is the usual expression in Australia. It's also common to **go for** a sauna. Interestingly, @JohnLawler, while Australians will often go for a shit, they'd never take one - the implication of the latter being theft of faeces...

Comment: I'm from Canada, native speaker from the west coast. In Vancouver we have saunas in nearly every public pool, and yet this question stumps me. All I can add is that in my experience "go sit in the sauna" is the most common if the person saying it is at the facility that has the sauna. If they're going to a facility that has a sauna I hear "go use the sauna" sometimes followed by "at <insert facility name>". I have never in my recollection heard "take a sauna", and it sounds awkward to my ears.

Comment: @HusbandFatherCoder: I'm just south of you in Bellingham. Ditto for your intuitions.

Comment: @Josh61 I suspect your answer is the most technically accurate one, with the references you provided, and OP is asking if it's correct. It appears it is, and the rest is just colloquial / common usage that varies from place to place. Maybe OP  can confirm that's what he's looking for? Otherwise I suspect all of these options are grammatically correct, but that's not my forte.

Comment: @Josh61 You could make your comment an answer as it provides a credible source and therefore answers my original question.

Comment: @Josh61 Come on, friend, post that as an answer already! I'm dying to upvote it. :)

Comment: @imas145 - well, it actually is a GR question, the answer is a dictionary entry.

Comment: @HusbandFatherCoder Yes, go sit in the sauna. I agree with what you say. By the way, my pool in Massachusetts does have a sauna, but it's not in use at the moment. And another pool in my neighborhood also does, too. So, I guess it depends where you live.

Answer (score 4):

Wiktionary has [an appendix that includes collocations of 'take' and 'have'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Collocations_of_do,_have,_make,_and_take). It includes "'take'/'have' a bath" and "'take'/'have' a shower". 'Take' is more common in the US, 'have' in the UK.

The good news is that both terms are intelligible on both sides of the Pond and that most civilized people on either side wouldn't hold it against you that you used the less common, less preferred version.

Answer (score 0):

As a Finn-American I was always directed by my Finlander fam to say take sauna.

I think this might have derived post Finland as the UP of Michigan (where my Grandmother was from) didn't always do the best grammatically while speaking.

"I am going to take sauna." Notice- not "a" sauna. Take sauna (sow-na not saw-na).

Comment: Sowing seeds is an odd pronunciation.

Comment: Hello, Rachel. At the risk of sounding racist, ELU looks at _standard_ English. [These Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+sauna%2Ctake+a+sauna%2Ctake+sauna&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20sauna%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20sauna%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20sauna%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20sauna%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20sauna%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20sauna%3B%2Cc0) indicate that 'take sauna' is not the usual expression. // I've checked some examples; one or two seem kosher, though many have dubious grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we Finns really have a verb for having sauna, it is 'saunoa'. But typically in Finnish we just say I'm going in to the sauna - 'menen saunaan'. Going surely is not very English, but I find it un-sauna-like to take a sauna. Like someone here said, you don't take it anywhere, and you surely don't take it as a whole, but often together with someone else. For me as a Finn, the preferable English expression would be 'I'm going to have sauna', though of course, this is a non-native linguist's insight into the matter.

Comment: Although *going to the sauna* is not established in English as **the** standard expression for this activity, it is  perfectly OK, especially given that most English-speaking people don't have saunas in their homes, so some going, in the literal sense, is usually involved. One goes to the sauna in the same way in which one goes to the pool.

Answer (score -3):

I never take a shower or a sauna. To where would I take them? I typically shower (i.e. use the noun as a verb), but I'm not happy with sauna as a verb. I tend to "use the sauna" or "go into the sauna". I don't even like to "have" a shower or a sauna; to me this simply implies ownership. (I used to be able to "bathe" but I no longer have a bath, having replaced mine with a shower.)

I dislike both, but find "have" preferable to "take". Although, American probably favours "take".

Comment: So, do you never *take* a photo? And you never *have* breakfast because that would mean you possess this meal....

Comment: This could be a good comment, not a good answer, IMHO.

Comment: I definitely TAKE a photo. I have something that I did not previously have: I took it. I tend to EAT breakfast, since I already have it. We could wait along time for an answer to a question which is subjective. That which is in common use tends to become the correct way of using it. If having a sauna is the most broadly used, have saunas. The language is dynamic. It's not French.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I was searching for an indisputably correct delexical usage of 'take', hopefully not in the bath / leak domain, then saw your example.

Comment: Anyone who read the OP would recognise that "sauna" was the subject, not photos. Nevertheless, I'll indulge you again: of course I "take" a photograph. It's literally correct to removing an image from where it started to somewhere else. Note to the downvoters: I should like to see our OP, Sami, walking around carrying a sauna or a shower with them. Nope. Unless you're a handyman, you don't "take" a shower.